# webSQL floating point issue

Tags: javascript, cordova

I am working with the PhoneGap API on Android.  The API emulates webSQL for storage.  I have encountered an issue, and I'm not sure whether to attribute it to my limited knowledge of JavaScript, or to something I'm missing with PhoneGap / WebSQL.

Long story short, I'm storing UNIX epoch timestamps as a FLOAT via WebSQL.

```
        tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO timeline VALUES(0, 10, 100, 1297618964.65, '2011-02-13')");
        tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO timeline VALUES(0, 8, 120, 1297618985.65, '2011-02-13')");
```

These values are then queried with a simple select statement and read with the following code:

```
        for (i = 0; i < results.rows.length; i++){
            console.log(results.rows.item(i).timestamp);
            timestamps.push(results.rows.item(i).timestamp);
            weights.push(results.rows.item(i).intensity);    
        }
```

The issue is that the "timestamp" value appears to be truncated.  The log shows 1.29762e+09, and the resulting graphs I'm plotting reflect this loss of precision.

Using parseFloat or toFixed here gives the same loss of precision, just in a different printable format.  The table definition is using FLOAT for timestamp, so I'm at a bit of a loss as to why my values are transformed thus before I do anything with them.

Answer (score 0):

can you use DOUBLE for the field in the table definition?

and why is your timestamp a float? do you need them like that? in javascript timestamps are milliseconds since epoch as integer. i have no problem storing such timestamps in webSQL in an application i write.
do you have miliseconds after the decimal point? then maybe you can multiply by 1000 and store as long int and divide 1000 again after loading it from the db.